# Calculate number of days between 2 dates in swift4 / Xcode9

Tags: ios, swift

currentCalendar.dateComponents(**components: Set Calendar.Component**,     from: **Date**, to: **Date**)

I want to calculate the number of days between 2 dates, I can't seem to find a tutorial anyway online for swift4 Xcode9 everything else seems to be about the outdated syntax. so I just want to know what should I put in the "**components: Set Calendar.Component**" part ?

Comment: `Set<Calendar.Component>` in your case is simply `[.day]`. The array notation will create the `Set` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put a Set of the enumeration type Calendar.Component

example:

```
let s: Set = [Calendar.Component.day]

let c = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dc = c.dateComponents(s, from: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: -100000), to: Date.init(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0))

let day = dc.day
```

the day variable is equal to 1

Comment: that literally didn't even answer what I asked